# Java generic type parameter naming convention scope

Tags: java, generics, naming-conventions

The [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) says that when there are multiple generic parameters, the convention is to use S,U,V etc. for the 2nd, 3rd, 4th types. Does this convention apply across the scope of one enclosing `<>` group, or across a class?

For example, if I have a class with two separate methods that use different generic parameters, does the above convention mean I should write the code like this:

```
public abstract class MyClass
{
    public abstract <T extends Class1> T method1();
    public abstract <S extends Class2> S method2();
}
```

Or like this:

```
public abstract class MyClass
{
    public abstract <T extends Class1> T method1();
    public abstract <T extends Class2> T method2();
}
```

Comment: Definitely the second way. The convention is to distinguish types in the same scope, similar to the convention of `i` and `j` for index variables.

Comment: Not sure there's a convention for this, but I personally would prefer the first one.  Much less chance of someone reading the code after you and being confused.

Comment: so opinion based?

Comment: @markspace If you feel that, do you also feel that parameter names for methods should be unique across the class? It's really the same thing. Method parameter name. Local type parameter name. --- What if you have 10+ generic methods like that, would use begin naming them `AA`, `AB`, etc?

Comment: See [`Collectors`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/stream/Collectors.html). All static factory methods are unrelated and all start with `T` for “type” again (though they use `U` as second type, the other letters are derived from they roles).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second is certainly more conventional. The first pattern won't hold up if you have a large utility class with generic methods.

We can see examples of this [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Collections.java#Collections) in openjdk, and in popular libraries like [this](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Streams.java) guava class. Note they both re-use T as a type variable in most methods. This allows other identifiers like E, K, V, etc to retain some semantic meaning.